# Wordpress default srcset with hard crop

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using hard-crop on featured images like this :

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size ( 635, 200, true );
```

I have no other settings for wordpress srcset or sizes in my functions.php.
So wordpress generates the srcsets for a featured image uploaded with resolution 1500x1048 as follows:

```
srcset="image?zoom=2&resize=635%2C200 1207w, image?zoom=3&resize=635%2C200 1905w" sizes="(max-width: 635px) 100vw, 635px
```

So it basically crops the image to 635 and then generates 2 versions of it, zoomed from 635 to 1207 and 1905. And needless to say that it loads the 1207 version for sizes smaller than 1905... even on 100x100 device screen it still loads 1207 width image.

Can you please advice on how to set srcset and sizes in functions.php (only for featured imgs) for a site with featured images maximum 635px on any device?

Comment: Those aren't standard WP image URLs. What plugin are you using?

Comment: Sorry I did not post the entire link . Instead of image? is a http://i0.wp.com/www.mysite.com/wp-content....?zoom=2...  I replaced the link with the "image" word. And I have Jetpack plugin enabled if that matters at all.

Comment: If you're using jetpack photon then I'm afraid I don't know enough about what it does to help.